# read.demogdata in R demography package

Tags: r

While using the demography package in R, I tried out the following example:

```
norway <- read.demogdata("Mx_1x1.txt", "Exposures_1x1.txt",
    type="mortality", label="Norway")
```

I obtained the following output.
Error in file(file, "rt") :

> cannot open the connection

In addition: Warning message:

> In file(file, "rt") :
>         cannot open file 'Mx_1x1.txt': No such file or directory

Why does that keep occuring? How can I overcome it and get a proper output?

Answer (score 1):

The `Mx_1x1.txt` and `Exposures_1x1.txt` are not available in the package itself I believe. The files are available from [this](http://www.mortality.org) website.

Save both files (exactly as they appear on the website) as .txt file and you should be OK.